# How to disable left legend in SfCartesianChart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I have SfCartesianChart and I want to disable visibility  of the left legend(0,50,100). How can I do this?

[image]

This is my code:

```
SfCartesianChart(
  plotAreaBorderWidth: 0, // X top line
  plotAreaBorderColor: Colors.white24,
  primaryXAxis: DateTimeAxis(
    majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks below X line
    majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(
      width: 0.5,
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
    axisLine: const AxisLine( // X bottom line
      color: Colors.white24,
      dashArray: <double>[5,5]
    ),
  ),
  primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
    majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 1, color: Colors.white24, dashArray: <double>[5, 5]),
    majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0), // Little sticks on left side
    axisLine: const AxisLine(
      color: Colors.transparent, // Y left line
      dashArray: <double>[5,5]
    ),
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 100,
  ),
)
```

I tried to add => labelPosition: const ChartDataLabelPosition(0), but ide returns me an error => Generative enum constructors can only be used as targets of redirection.
Try using an enum constant, or a factory constructor.

labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent helps me but there is still a space and I don't know how to to remove this space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meet the same problem, just add this:

```
primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
  labelStyle: const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    fontSize: 0
  ),
),
```